# Link to view PDF version of a Google Slides in browser

Tags: google-slides, pdf

I'm trying to create a link to a Google Slides presentation that will open in a browser as a PDF.  I've tried changing the end of the URL from `edit?usp=sharing` to `export?format=pdf` and a few variations with no success.  My suspicions were confirmed after reading this [article from how-to geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/400707/how-to-share-links-to-your-google-doc-as-a-pdf/) that asserts the technique does not work with Google Slides.  Does anyone know of a technique that does work on Google Slides or a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

As a regular presenter, it's pretty common that people want a copy of the slides. I happily share them when requested but always wondered if there was a way to understand which parts of the presentation they were really interested in.

You can [check out this tool](https://superslide.co) that I came across recently that allows for audiences to access a PDF of the presentation on demand while also delivering engagement stats to the presenter.

Pretty cool and has led to some good follow ups with potential customers for me.